# How to design a custom progress bar with rounded edges and slanting progress?

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, android-progressbar, rounded-corners

This is what I wish to achieve:
[Clicky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyUAS.png)

The container color, the progress color, the progress background color and the rounded edge radius as well as the thickness should all be editable and modifiable.

How could this be achieved with a light weight custom UI element?

Answer (score 2):

After days of research, I was able to achieve what was expected with clear crisp UI and with all the above requirements and flexibility. The exact above UI can be achieved and follow parameters can be achieved as well:
1. Progress Color
2. Progress background color
3. Container color (Color of container to be set by you, you can set color of rounded edges to match the container color)
4. Height and width of the progress bar to suit your needs.

Here's the code and steps to implement it:

I. Put this code in the **attrs.xml** file under the **values** folder

```
<declare-styleable name="SlantingProgressBar">
    <attr name="slantingProgress" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="borderRadius" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="borderColor" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="slantingProgressColor" format="string"/>
    <attr name="progressBackgroundColor" format="string"/>
    <attr name="slantingProgressFullColor" format="string"/>

</declare-styleable>
```

II. Create a java class like this:

```
public class SlantingProgressbar extends View {
private float height = 0;
private float width = 0;
private int borderRadius = 20;
private float progress = 0;

private int rawProgress = 0;
private static final String OPACITY_30_PERCENT = "#66";

private int roundedBorderColor;
private String backgroundColor = "";
private String progressColor = "";
private String progressFullColor = "#fc3d39";

public SlantingProgressbar(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public SlantingProgressbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray array = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.SlantingProgressBar,
            0, 0);

    try {
        setProgress(array.getInt(R.styleable.SlantingProgressBar_slantingProgress, 0));
        setBackgroundColor(array.getString(R.styleable.SlantingProgressBar_progressBackgroundColor));    //Default color set in the method
        setBorderRadius(array.getInt(R.styleable.SlantingProgressBar_borderRadius, 20));
        setRoundedBorderColor(array.getInt(R.styleable.SlantingProgressBar_borderColor, 0));
        setProgressColor(array.getString(R.styleable.SlantingProgressBar_slantingProgressColor));
    } finally {
        array.recycle();
    }
}

public void setBorderRadius(int borderRadius) {
    this.borderRadius = borderRadius;
}


public int getProgress() {
    return rawProgress;
}

public void setProgress(int progress) {
    if(progress >=0)
    {
        this.rawProgress = progress;
        this.invalidate();
    }
    else
        Log.e("ChlorophyllProgressBar", "Invalid 'progress' value detected, value should be between 0 and 100");

}


public void setRoundedBorderColor(int roundedBorderColor) {
    if ( roundedBorderColor == 0) {
        this.roundedBorderColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
        Log.e("CUSTOM_TAG", "Color set to White: " + this.roundedBorderColor);
        return;
    }

    this.roundedBorderColor = roundedBorderColor;
    Log.e("CUSTOM_TAG", "Color set to custom: " + this.roundedBorderColor);

}

private int getRoundedBorderColor()
{
    return roundedBorderColor;
}

public void setSlantingProgressFullColor(String color)
{
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(progressFullColor)) {
        this.progressFullColor = "#fc3d39";
        return;
    }
}


public void setBackgroundColor(String backgroundColor) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(backgroundColor)) {
        this.backgroundColor = "#bfe8d4";
        return;
    }

    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
}


public void setProgressColor(String progressColor) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(progressColor)) {
        this.progressColor = "#2bb673"; //Green
        return;
    }
    this.progressColor = progressColor;
}

public float getViewHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setViewHeight(float height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public float getViewWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setViewWidth(float width) {
    this.width = width;
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    height = getHeight();
    width = getWidth();
    progress = getProcessedProgress();

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    paint.setColor(getProcessedProgressColor());
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    Log.d("CUSTOM_TAG", "Height: " + height);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, progress, height, paint);


    Path triangle = new Path();
    triangle.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

    triangle.moveTo(progress, 0);
    triangle.lineTo(progress + height, 0);
    triangle.lineTo(progress, height);
    triangle.close();

    canvas.drawPath(triangle, paint);

    drawBorders(canvas, getRoundedBorderColor());
}


private void drawBorders(Canvas canvas, int color) {
    float height = getHeight();
    float trueWidth = getWidth();

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(color);
    //paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    Path border = new Path();

    border.moveTo(0, 0);
    border.lineTo(0, height / 2);
    border.quadTo(height / borderRadius, height / borderRadius, height / 2, 0);
    border.lineTo(0, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(border, paint);

    border.reset();

    border.moveTo(0, height);
    border.lineTo(height / 2, height);
    border.quadTo(height / borderRadius, (height - height / borderRadius), 0, height / 2);
    border.lineTo(0, height);

    canvas.drawPath(border, paint);

    border.reset();

    border.moveTo(trueWidth, 0);
    border.lineTo(trueWidth - (height / 2), 0);
    border.quadTo((trueWidth - height / borderRadius), height / borderRadius, trueWidth, height / 2);
    border.lineTo(trueWidth, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(border, paint);

    border.reset();

    border.moveTo(trueWidth, height);
    border.lineTo(trueWidth - (height / 2), height);
    border.quadTo((trueWidth - height / borderRadius), (height - height / borderRadius), trueWidth, height / 2);
    border.lineTo(trueWidth, height);

    canvas.drawPath(border, paint);

    //Adding 1 pixel color
    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
    paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    int fadedColor = (color & 0x00FFFFFF) | 0x66000000;
    Log.d("CUSTOM_TAG", "Faded Color Code: " + fadedColor);
    paint1.setColor(fadedColor);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 1, height, paint1);
    canvas.drawRect(trueWidth-1, 0, trueWidth, height, paint1);
}

private float getProcessedProgress()
{
    return (rawProgress == 99) ? ((getWidth() * 98) / 100) : ((getWidth() * rawProgress) / 100);
}

private int getProcessedProgressColor()
{
    if(rawProgress > 100)
    {
        return Color.parseColor(progressFullColor);
    }
    else
    {
        return Color.parseColor(progressColor);
    }


}
}
```

III. To use the layout in your xml file:

```
<com.whatever.package.SlantingProgressbar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimension1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        slanting_progress:borderColor="@color/darkgray"
        android:layout_below="@id/alphacon_detail"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/budget_list_item_paddingBottom"
        android:progress="50" />
```

I'm sharing this code after a little while, so I might have missed out a thing or two, I'm pretty sure you can get that worked out, please feel free to correct me.

Explanation:
We're using the **'draw'** methods in java to implement this feature. The advantage is that, drawing a UI element gives us a sharp and clear UI no matter how big or small you make it.
There might be some hardcoded values, so be sure to edit those before implementing.

Good luck and don't forget to up-vote if this post helps you. Thanks! :)

Comment: I've added a new answer with some performance improvements on your code. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post an answer here to show some improvements on your code.

- You should avoid creating new objects during `draw`.

`draw` is called several times again and again to redraw your custom element and all those calls to `new Paint()` are creating new objects, that needs new memory allocation, and it drives the garbage collector crazy and makes your View much more resource intensive and probably will cause lag on scrolling elements such as `RecyclerView`.

Alternatively you should have them declared as `private Paint border` and then `private Paint triangle`, etc, etc. And then you should initialise the values of All the paints in a separate method and only if the parameters changed. An example code:

```
private boolean initPaint = false;
private void initPaintsIfNecessary(){
   if(!initPaint) return;
   initPaint = false;

   triangle = new Paint();
   triangle.set.... etc

   border = new Paint();
   border.set.... etc
}
```

then on all the methods `setRoundedBorderColor`, `setProgressColor`, etc. You call `initPaint = true;` and on the beginning of `draw` you call `initPaintsIfNecessary();`. This will avoid all the extra garbage collector work and will allow the UI of your app to run much smoother.

That also includes all the `Paint` inside `drawBorders` method.

- use `format="color" instead of`string`.

Calling `Color.parse(String)` is a very slow call and it is very error prone. Alternatively you should the correct `color` element, like following:

```
<attr name="slantingProgressColor" format="color"/>
```

that not just is the correct way, but gives you a color preview on the editor, can be indexed on app style parameters and avoid this inefficient call to `parse`

then of course you should adjust or method appriately. For example:
    setProgressColor(array.getColor(R.styleable.SlantingProgressBar_slantingProgressColor));

`getColor` will return an integer that can be directly used in `paint.setColor(int);`

I hope those tips can help you (and others in the community) to create better more efficient `View` elements. Happy coding!

Comment: Hello Budius, thank you for the review. I had no idea that the Draw method is called several times. Shall look more into that soon. 
I definitely agree on the color resource string, got a bit lazy to declare the color resource string while posting the solution. :P

Answer (score 0):

I know this this old question to answer but this answer may helpful..
You can use drawArc method to achieve this..

```
RectF oval = new RectF();
oval.set(left, top ,right, bottom);
canvas.drawArc(oval, 270, 360, false, paint);
```